# How to to acces process-safe container in multiprocessing.Pool

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have the following set-up:

```
import multiprocessing
def heavy_work(args):
    queue, data, idx = args
    state = 0
    for elem in queue:
        #  decide how to process current data point, store collected information in 'state'
    else:
        queue.put(modify(data[idx], state))


def mp_heavy_work(data):
    queue = multiprocessing.Manager().Queue(len(data))
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
    pool.map(heavy_work, ((queue, data, i) for i in range(len(data))))
```

Problem is, queues are not iterable, so line 5 does not work. I need to know how previous data points were modified in order to decide for new ones, so reading the write-access shared container (currently `queue`) is necessary. I wanted to rely on a 'primitive' process-safe type instead of locks, because the main effort is done inside the loop -- so locking it each time a process enters makes the multiprocessing redundant.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need it to be iterable?  You can just use the normal `queue.get()`.

```
try:
    while True:
        elem = queue.get(False)
        # do stuff with elem
except Queue.Empty:
    queue.put(modify(data[idx], state))
```

If you really want an iterable, you can wrap your queue object:

```
for elem in iter(queue.get, 'sentinal'):
    # do stuff
else:
    # do more stuff
```

This will call queue.get on each iteration until it hits a 'sentianal' object, then it will `StopIteration`.  This way you can manually close the queue.

If you want to do the `else` block when the queue is empty (without manually ending the iteration), you must rely on the Queue.Empty exception:

```
try:
    for elem in iter(lambda:queue.get(False), 'sentinal'):
        # do stuff        
except Queue.Empty:
    # do else stuff
```

You could even wrap this up in your own custom wrapper:

```
def wrap(queue):
    try:
        for elem in iter(lambda:queue.get(False), 'sentinal'):
            yield elem
        else:
            # this is executed if the 'sentinal' is sent
            # may want to special handle this (throw custom exception?)
    except Queue.Empty:
        pass # just enter iteration

...

    for elem in wrap(queue):
        # do stuff
    else:
        # do more stuff
```

Comment: I didn't want to use 'get' because it consumes the element (unless I understood something very basic very wrong). The way you wrote it, the queue will always hold only the last value.

Comment: I guess I assumed you were consuming values that another process pushed into the queue.  Why else use a queue?  If that's not the case than it's not clear what you're doing (that part of the code is blank), could you clarify what you are trying to access?

Comment: I see, I didn't know queues consume elements on offering. What happens in the blank code is a classification. All currently inserted data is compared to the new data point, and if a sufficiently similar cluster is found, that information is passed in the 'state' parameter on putting it in the queue -- or if none was found, the new entry forms his own class. 

So, there never is any tossing of elements during the process.

Comment: I may not be understanding you correctly, but what you describe sounds like you need to process the data points one at a time (they depend on previously processed points).  If this is the case you wouldn't want to use multiprocessing.

Comment: You probably understand correctly, because you're right that multiprocessing can lead to different solutions. But the whole procedure takes hours, and I think the likelihood of an inconsistency is rather low, which is why I wanted to see if I can make this work.